# How to calculate $\cos$(number) or $\sin$(number) without use of a scientific calculator?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can somebody please help me how to calculate numerical value for $f(x)=-18\cos (3x)$ where $x=5$ so $f(5)=-18\cos(15)$ I am allowed to use only simple calculator and I don't know how to find the numerical value for this function. How much is $\cos(15)$ and how can I find how much cosine (of a number)is without using calculator with special functions?

I also don't know what to do with $\sin $(number) example $f(x)=-6\sin (3x)$ where $x=5 - f(5)=-6\sin (15)$
How much is $\sin (15)$ and how can I find how much is sine (of a number) without using calculator with special functions?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can always approximate with trig identities, but if you’re in degrees. There is a closed form for sin and cos 15

Comment: Short method: use old school trig tables. Longer method: Taylor series. An exact for also exist if needed (half angle formula)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2815+degrees%29

Comment: You wrote "allowed to use only simple calculator" and so your question should be directed to those responsible for that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha = 15°$ you can do it without calculator.

But it's not so easy for any $\alpha$, i.e. it's not always possible
to get a nice solution (say in radicals) with paper and pencil only.

First of all $$\sin(30°) = 1/2$$ this is well-known to you, I assume.

Then probably you also know that

$$\cos(30°) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

But then using the double-angle formula gives us

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos(30°) = 2 \cos^2{15°} - 1 $$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos(30°) = 1 - 2 \sin^2{15°}$$

Solving the last 2 equations
(while keeping in mind that $\sin{15°} \gt 0$ and $\cos{15°} \gt 0$ )
gives us the exact values for $\sin{15°}$ and $\cos{15°}$

$$\cos(15°) = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$
$$\sin(15°) = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$